# iTunes and iPod Touch "Payment was declined"

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-touch, paypal

I recently bought a new iPod Touch 5 and made 3 purchases. The last app I purchased downloaded successfully onto my iPod but I never got an email receipt from the store. So I checked my purchase history and it says

> "We were unable to authorize your credit card for this purchase.
>   Please update your billing info."

So I went to the "Billing Info" page and validated my PayPal account. Now it says

> "Your PayPal transaction was declined."

I tried adding a credit card as my payment option and I get:

> "Your credit card was declined. Please enter valid credit card information."

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Call them, they will love to take your money.

Comment: Check your PayPall or Credit card to see if they have deducted the money since you got the product already.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my bank was declining the purchases. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you double-check all of the information you are entering. Even being one digit off in the credit card number or expiration date can cause issues. Also ensure that your billing address matches exactly what your bank has on file for your credit card or debit card.

If all else fails, contact [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/). From this link, select "Contact iTunes Store support". On the next screen, choose "Purchases, Billing and Redemption", then "Unable to purchase from App Store". On the following screen it will provide possible solutions as well as ways to directly contact iTunes support.